# Error running UAA login.rb sample

Tags: cloud-foundry

I've been investigating a CF deployment scenario in which I have an existing authentication infrastructure, and I need to configure UAA to delegate the login to the existing SSO authority.  As a first step I decided to use the login.rb sample server, just to get things going.

I've set up my environment with the sample login.rb and the sample app running on localhost and a UAA instance running on another host.  The redirect from the app to the login page at localhost:3000 is working, and looking at my logs I can see that the (pass-through) authentication is successful when the login.rb sample does the post to UAA, and in addition the response received to the post to authorise also gives 200 OK....I can see the JSON with the needed prompt strings is being returned.  However, a problem occurs with the erb confirmation dialogue.  I'm getting an exception at line 124 of the login.rb

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass:
    /home/fieldj1/Documents/workspace-sts-3.1.0.RELEASE/uaa/samples/login/login.rb:124:in `block in <class:LoginApplication>'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `call'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1212:in `block in compile!'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:785:in `[]'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:785:in `block (3 levels) in route!'
    /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/sinatra-1.3.2/lib/sinatra/base.rb:801:in `route_eval'
 ...
```

The problem seems to be that the code that parses the JSON OAUTH response from UAA is out of date.  I fixed it by changing line 124 from this:

```
erb :confirm, :locals => {:client_id => confirmation_info["authorizationRequest" ["clientId"], \
                          :scopes => confirmation_info["authorizationRequest"]["scope"]}
```

to this:

```
erb :confirm, :locals => {:client_id => confirmation_info["auth_request"]["authorizationParameters"]["client_id"], \
                                :scopes => confirmation_info["auth_request"]["authorizationParameters"]["scope"]}
```

Has anyone else seen this?  I'm fairly certain that the code I am running should be self-consistent since I did a git clone of the whole UAA.  Not sure if my environment is somehow inconsistent, or if I found a real issue.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a real issue, in the sense that the ruby sample is not up to date, and no-one has got round to updating it because we don't use it anywhere.  If you can send a pull request that would be awesome.

Comment: OK, I'll make a pull request shortly.  I saw that there were changes afoot with the samples.  But this earlier sample had the advantage of being very lightweight and easy to run/experiment on my development VM.  Thanks, John

Answer (score 0):

We are currently working on updating all our docs and sample app examples, the login ruby sample app that you are using is currently out-dated. You are welcome to make a pull request.

In the meanwhile you can take a look at the new docs, its work in progress : http://cloudfoundry.github.com/.

Thanks,
- Hitesh

Comment: Thanks, Hitesh, I'll check out the new docs, and make a pull request shortly.